# Show hide content onClick with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you all can help me out here. I'm trying to hide some `td` elements and have them shown when I click on a button. I've go this working. But there is no smooth animation.

What I would like is to have the `td` elements `fadeIn` and the `Click me` button slide down this all in one smooth animation. And if I click the `Click me` button again the `td` elements `fadeOut` and the button slides up.

I've got this working, but the there is no animation, it look choppy. Is there a way to have this work smooth and nicer looking?

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clicked" style="display:none;">
      text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clicked" style="display:none;">
      text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clicked" style="display:none;">
      text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="text-center click">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
$('.click').on('click touchstart', function() {
    $('.clicked').slideToggle(); 
});
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/73tkr4ht/9/

I've used `slideToggle` because that seems to work... Any beter solutions/help please. And thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Since you are using JQuery, why not use JQuery's .animate() ?

Comment: I'd love too. Only kind of new to the whole animation jQeury... I would need to work with the top margin and so on?

Comment: Here is a link to it's documentation (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Yup, I'm reading that now.. thanks

Comment: No problem, it gives a good example close to the bottom. I think that should get you moving the right direction.